# writev on windows

Tags: c, windows, unix, file-io

Does Windows offer anything similar to writev in a non Cygwin environment?

Ideally, an answer would have a working example for windows, something along the lines of:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>

int main() {
  struct iovec iov[2];
  char blah[][20] = { "mickey", " mouse" };
  int fd = open ("/tmp/mice.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
  iov[0].iov_base=blah[0];
  iov[1].iov_base=blah[1];
  iov[0].iov_len=iov[1].iov_len=6;
  writev(fd, iov, 2 );
  close(fd);
}
```

The answer should be how to approach the problem using system calls. Specifically I am looking to avoid copying the individual buffers into a single larger buffer to perform the write. Also the resultant write should be a single large write request instead of something like fwrite which performs buffered IO.

---

***Edit**: 13 August 12*

The link to Scatter Gather I/O seems to pertain primarily to TCP/IP networking (err winsock really). Another suggestion, which is writefilegather is a solution for writing files in a very specific format. I.e. whereas writev writes using iov containers (arbitrary blocks of memory), writefilegather uses fixed buffers aligned to page table size.

Comment: [Scatter/gather I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740138(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Scatter/gather I/O link seems to pertain to windows sockets, this is for file descriptors.

Comment: [WriteFileGather](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365749%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Mind you, I am not a windows programmer. My help is more about search terms.

Comment: btw, writefilegather is a solution to a different problem... but ty for your suggestions.

Comment: Note that `WriteFileGather` _looks like, but very much isn't_ `writev`. There is no guarantee about atomicity whatsoever. All it does is save you a few syscalls by accepting an array of pointers to several data locations, but essentially it's not much different from calling `WriteFile` many times.

Answer (score 4):

[WSASend function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can send an array of WSABUF structures